# How to display real-time customised text in customised format?

Tags: python, real-time, display

I have (financial) data that I get in real time using an API and I'd like to display it in a customised manner (a bit like the result of a javascript code). For example, if I want to display 10x10 prices and update them as I receive the data and customise them to be green if it is higher than the previous price, red if lower or so, how should I do, what should I use?

I assume there exist a way to do so using python, but I can't formulate my demand briefly so I only get results that confuse me more using search engines...

Could someone help me by explaining where I can get started with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an overview because what you want is a generalized approach and most UI packages (if not all) should be able to handle this. First, you need to pick a package to write your UI with. There are a number of these available for Python: [see here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming). I'm not sure what your other requirements are so you'll have to choose the one you want yourself. Once you've picked it out, you'll basically go through and create a grid structure composed of individual cells. Each cell will contain a currency value. You'll then add an event for each cell that captures an "on-change" event for the value in the cell. If the new value is greater than the old one, you color it green. If it's less, color it red. You may also want to add a timer for each cell so that the color fades after a period of time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's a good beginning for what I'm looking in your link ! 
I am just a novice to Python so I don't know how reliable are the vairous UI (by the way, thank you for bringing this term to my knowledge). I am just looking for one that can handle relatively simple task and that is popular, I don't know, pygame, I prefereably don't want it displayed in a browser, more in a pop-up window ? I will look more in detail, the link, but if you have suggestions it would also be appreciated, but thank you already !

Comment: @Psy I started Python UI programming with Tkinter. That's the one that comes with Python. If you're just looking to learn, that might be a good place to start